# Conditional output in Sphinx Documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm writing some documentation with [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org) and I'd like to print out a certain block of text only for HTML documentation, not for LaTeX documentation. Something tells me I should be able to do this with `sphinx.ext.ifconfig` but I can't figure out how. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No extension is required. Just use the `only` directive.

(old link, from original 2010 post)
https://web.archive.org/web/20100129001557/http://sphinx.pocoo.org/markup/misc.html#including-content-based-on-tags

(latest link)
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#including-content-based-on-tags

It works like this:

```
.. only:: latex

    The stuff in here only appears in the latex output.

.. only:: html

    The stuff in this block only appears in the HTML output. It's
    often useful to use this directive with it:

    .. raw:: html

        It's good for embedding stuff, like video.
```

Comment: Is it possible to discern between `singlehtml` and `html` ?

Comment: @Carel yes, with Sphinx 1.2 and later, you can distinguish between `html` and `singlehtml` by using the explicit builder tags `builder_html` and `builder_singlehtml`.

Comment: could you please take a look at a similar question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798152/adding-custom-tag-in-sphinx

Comment: The link to the Sphinx doc on `only` is dead. See: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#including-content-based-on-tags