# How do I use SPHINXOPTS to trigger the "only" directive when invoking Sphinx with a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am generating a PDF via Sphinx using the [autogenerated Makefile](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/tutorial.html#running-the-build). I usually generate it using:

```
make latexpdf
```

However, I am now including the [only](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/misc.html#including-content-based-on-tags) directive, so that [some sections appear conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215518/conditional-output-in-sphinx-documentation) (this should happen if I include the relevant tag at the command line).

I added the following reST markup to my source file:

```
Hello world

.. only:: draft

          This is some draft content.
```

I tried generating the PDF as follows:

```
SPHINXOPTS="-t draft" make latexpdf
```

...but the output is the same as if I'd just run `make latexpdf` as normal, the "only" section does not appear. Is there a problem in my reST or my command line invocation?

(Also, I'd like to specify multiple tags if possible, e.g. `draft` and `admin`.)

Comment: Does it work if you run `make latexpdf SPHINXOPTS="-t draft"`?

Comment: @mzjn doh and thanks - do you want to make that an answer? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to modify the command a little (the variable assignment must come after `make`). Either of these work for me (using GNU make):

```
make SPHINXOPTS="-t draft" latexpdf
```

or

```
make latexpdf SPHINXOPTS="-t draft"
```