# How can I generate rst file in parts of directory into HTML file in Sphinx?

Tags: python, makefile, python-sphinx, exclusionpath

Display my Sphinx project's directory structure.

```
cd myproject/source
tree -d
.
├── django
├── document
├── excel
├── github
├── _images
├── _templates
└── vim
```

Everytime I execute the command `make html`, all the `*.rst` files in `django, document, excel, github, vim` will be generated into `*.html`. Now I want to only generate parts of `*.rst` file into `*.html`, say, I want to keep all the `*.rst` files in `github` and `vim` un-maked, how to execute the `make html` command?

Comment: It's hard being more precise without knowing if your index.rst holds dependencies to the files in those folders you want to exclude. Further elaborating the answer without more information about specific layout would give solutions that can require some slight adaptations of the rst files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice by looking inside the `make` file it's just a generated batch or shell script (depending on OS) that calls `sphinx-build` for you setting the arguments to default values.

```
set SPHINXBUILD=sphinx-build
set BUILDDIR=build
set SOURCEDIR=source

(...)

%SPHINXBUILD% -M %1 %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS% %O%
```

Equivalent to the signature from the documentation:

> [`sphinx-build [options] <sourcedir> <outputdir> [filenames …]`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#synopsis)

> say, I want to keep all the *.rst file in github and vim un-maked

The easiest way to achieve what you want, is excluding the directories you don't want to build:

`sphinx-build -b html ./source ./build -D exclude-patterns=github/*,vim/*`

The [`-D setting=value`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-D) option is equivalent to passing the `exclude-patterns=[]` normally found in your `conf.py` through the command line.

> how to execute the make html command?

If you want to use the `make` file you can also pass the above arguments to `make html` using `SPHINXOPTS`. [Some users got it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17065372/), however I haven't been able to on Windows.

A more complicated option, that may be necessary depending how you want to layout your documentation, would be to have an individual Sphinx project for every source directory, with its own `make.bat`, `conf.py` and `index.rst`. If you have a single `index.rst` that by default links to `.rst` files in the excluded directories, you may have to [conditionally exclude parts of `index.rst`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215518/conditional-output-in-sphinx-documentation).

Notice the [-c](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-c) and [-C](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-C) options.