# Adding custom tag in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx tool for documentation and ran into a situation where I want to expose a piece of information in only one file format.
I came across [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215518/conditional-output-in-sphinx-documentation) which addresses a similar issue with help of only directive.

The issue I am facing is I want to use the only directive with a custom tag

```
.. only:: xyz

  ..directive ::
    :maxdepth: 1

    good_stuff
```

I am using a setup.py file for building, and running BuildDoc.run(self) to generate the html files. I want somehow pass this custom tag in the setup.py file. I tried doing this, but seems like we cant access tags object from within setup.py file.

```
 def run(self):
    self.builder = 'html'
    *self.tags.add(xyz)*
    BuildDoc.run(self)
    self.zip("html.zip")
```

If I add tags.add('xyz') in the conf.py file, it will always expose the additional information, what I want to do is conditionally add this tag in my setup.py file.
I assume the make command does something similar by passing the tag info to the conf.py file but I am not sure how it works.

Answer (score 2):

The sphinx-build command accepts a `-t` option, which allows you to specify a tag you can then use in an `only` condition.

From `sphinx-build --help`:

```
    -t TAG            define tag: include "only" blocks with TAG
```

So using something like:

```
sphinx-build -t xyz
```

Will allow you to use the `.. only:: xyz` conditional inline.

---

It seems to me that if you want to conditionally apply tags in your setup.py file, you'd have to write the logic yourself to determine if you should include `self.tags.add('xyz')` or not.

Comment: I added `tags.add('my-tag')` in `conf.py`. And the line highlights in conf.py and says tags is not defined. Can you please tell the right steps how to use this? What is the right usage of command . I am using: `sphinx-build -t my-tag . build/html`, I get: `WARNING: exception while evaluating only directive expression: chunk after expression`