# Sphinx: Any way to add conditional content on a per-file basis?

Tags: python-sphinx

(Note: this is similar to [Conditional output in Sphinx Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215518), but it's not clear if the solution there is usable.)

I have some documentation of two functions that are very similar. What I *want* to write is a file that would be included by the doc for both that looks like:

```
.. if:: doc_for_foo
  This documentation only applies to ``foo``.

.. if:: doc_for_bar
  This documentation only applies to ``bar``.

This documentation applies to both.
```

So, the common content would appear in *two separate pages* of the same generated documentation. Is there a way to do this? (I know about `.. only`, but it isn't clear how I would enable the relevant bits for each documentation page.)

Note: I don't want to just split the common stuff into separate files, because the content is significantly interleaved. That is, I would end up with:

```
Text about ``foo``.

.. include:: common-part-1

More text.

.. include:: common-part-2

.. for 'foo', no intervening text here

.. include:: common-part-3

More text.

.. include:: common-part-4
```

...and so on, where each part is perhaps a single paragraph. IOW, the former would be much easier to maintain.

---

To clarify, I want something like:

```
.. foo.rst

.. enable-tag:: doc_for_foo
.. include:: foo_and_bar_doc
```

```
.. bar.rst

.. enable-tag:: doc_for_bar
.. include:: foo_and_bar_doc
```

...where both `foo.rst` and `bar.rst` are generated by *the same run* of Sphinx. Passing `-t` at build time won't work; both `foo.rst` and `bar.rst` would (AFAIU) see the same set of tags set. Same with anything I did in `conf.py`.

Comment: Did you actually try using the directive [`only`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#including-content-based-on-tags)? It does exactly what you want.

Comment: @StevePiercy, did you *read* the question? "I know about `.. only`, but it isn't clear how I would enable the relevant bits for each documentation page." If you know how to use `.. only` for this purpose, please post an answer. To wit, how do I enable a "tag" *for a specific page*?

Comment: Did you *read* the documentation for `only` about how to use it? If that documentation is not clear about its usage, then what about it is not clear?

Comment: @StevePiercy, what part of "how do I enable a "tag" for a specific page?" was unclear? I can see how to affect `.. only` for *an entire build*. I *do not* see how to affect it on a per-page basis. Since you obviously are seeing something I am not, please elucidate.

Comment: What part of the documentation that states "Undefined tags are false, defined tags (via the -t command-line option or within conf.py, see [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#conf-tags)) are true. Boolean expressions, also using parentheses (like html and (latex or draft)) are supported." was not clear?

Comment: @StevePiercy, what part of "via the -t command-line option or within conf.py" explains how to set those *per page*? How am I not communicating clearly?

Comment: I cannot help you when you do not read the whole sentence and follow the linked reference: "...see [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#conf-tags)) are true." Perhaps your snark got in the way?

Comment: @StevePiercy, "Undefined tags are false, defined tags (via the -t command-line option or within conf.py, see here) are true" is a) perfectly clear, and b) not helpful in accomplishing what I want to accomplish. I guess the *useful* answer would be "write an extension providing a custom directive that allows manipulating the tags" (assuming it's even possible to manipulate them via a directive).